# Property 'hasOwnProperty' does not exist on a non-null non-undefined generic type

Tags: typescript

I have a code which looks like this (T is a generic):

```
if (!(item as Exclude<T, null | undefined>).hasOwnProperty(this.idKey)) {
    throw new Error("...");
}
```

and I get a TypeScript error:

`TS2339: Property 'hasOwnProperty' does not exist on type 'Exclude '.`

How is it possible this type does not have the `hasOwnProperty`, if `hasOwnProperty` is a method of the `Object` class? Are there any types other than `null` and `undefined` in TypeScript which are not (directly or via autoboxing) instances of `Object`?

Comment: How is T defined?

Comment: `class FooBar<T> {`

Comment: Yeah so T could be anything... Including things that aren't objects.

Answer (score 0):

Note what [`Exclude`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludeuniontype-excludedmembers) does:

> Constructs a type by excluding from UnionType all union members that are assignable to ExcludedMembers.

So `null` and `undefined` can easily be values of `Exclude<T, null | undefined>`. E.g. if `T` is `any`, there are no union members to exclude:

```
const x: Exclude<any, null | undefined> = null;
```

And so you can't call `x.hasOwnProperty(...)`.